# Laravel 5.4 Tests - Can not login

Tags: php, laravel, unit-testing, phpunit

I'm trying to login as a user with my Laravel test with the following code:

```
class AdminTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->admin = factory(User::class)->create([
                'is_admin'  => true,
            ]);
    }

    public function test_admin_can_create_clients()
    {
        $this->startSession()
            ->actingAs($this->admin, 'web')
            ->get('/clients')
            ->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

However I am always getting a fail:

> 1) Tests\Feature\AdminTest::test_admin_can_create_clients
>
> Expected status code 200 but received 403. Failed asserting that false is true.

When I did some googling I found I have to `startSession` but even that didn't work.

I tried using `be` but got the following error:

> 1) Tests\Feature\AdminTest::test_admin_can_create_clients
>
> Error: Call to a member function get() on null

How can I login a user through my test and have it persist for multiple pages in the same test?

Thanks

Comment: impersonate user with `be`

Comment: Tried it already. See update. @Thamilan

Comment: I don't know if it is of much use but in my own application I use `$this->actingAs($user)->get(...);`, so removing the `startSession` and removing the `/web/` argument.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
class AdminTest extends TestCase
{
    use DatabaseMigrations;

    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->admin = factory(User::class)->create([
                'is_admin'  => true,
            ]);
        // Impersonate as the currently created admin user
        $this->be($this->admin);
    }

    public function test_admin_can_create_clients()
    {
        // You do not need to use actingAs() if you're already using be()
        $this->get('/clients')->assertStatus(200);
    }
}
```

I guess this should be working fine.